# creating 3D placeholders in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder

What is the difference in creating 3D placeholders using for loop and shape as follows.

```
batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(num_relations, None, 3))
```

vs.

```
batch_placeholders = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, 3), name='batch_'+str(i)) for i in range(num_relations)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(num_relations, None, 3))
```

Returns a Tensor with the given shape, whereby None is here a variable indicating that the size of this dimension is defined later on.

```
batch_placeholders = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, 3), name='batch_'+str(i)) for i in range(num_relations)]
```

This returns a list of tensors all having the same given shape (first dimension of variable size and second dimension of size 3, but their name property is different depending on the `i` variable.

If you would like to have the dimension size in your shape argument also be defined by the `i` variable it should be like in the following snippet. Depends only on what you wanna do.

```
batch_placeholders = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(i, None, 3), name='batch_'+str(i)) for i in range(num_relations)]
```

Check also here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder

Comment: wouldn't the shape of second method be same? which method would be more efficient?

Comment: No, the function returns one tensor object every time you call it. The second time you create `i` tensor objects, the first time only one and their shapes are different.